Encrypt amount in transaction with solana program
Hey i know that its possible to encrypt the amount sent in transaction to be hiden. However i cannot find any example. Is there any good example of such program and usage with JS? Basically im trying to just send the transaction through this program using @solana/web3.js, or any other library that's here, without too much changes in my code. Thanks!
I also would prefer to not show the program source code, but not sure if that's possible using Anchor.

I don't think this is implemented yet natively in Solana. You might have to use token extensions for this or create your own program for doing this like elusive now actum did.

Everything is public by default on Solana, you cannot hide the amount of SOL you sent. Previously we had Elusiv, however they now transitioned into building Arcium and doing something bigger.
With token extensions, though, you can create tokens that have confidential transfers. Check it out here: https://spl.solana.com/confidential-token/quickstart
Another solution that you can consider, though not very efficient or effective, is to create intermediate wallets through which you can pass SOL. However that can also be easily traced back really.

Yeah it's fine if it's possible to reverse that, i just ran through this transaction https://solscan.io/tx/3WWoddR7kzguCw5PjVD1t3M5Z45aXCgJc6MXvpgbU6YHCpU14MHFdPvCNceoEmcP37Q9nAz5L8cJtvqnHAwQ3fDx and thought it will be cool to learn coding solana programs with such project. Do you think the quickstart with confidential tokens will be enough to make something like that in this transaction?
